# How to pass List in ImageCarousel?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am working with [ImageCarousel](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_carousel) library. I have image URLs in a list that I am getting from my server and now I want to show these images in an ImageCarousel. I've tried many methods but I am unable to pass the whole list. I am stuck with this piece of code, please help me.

Here is my code:

```
List<NetworkImage> networkimages;

for(int i=0 ; i< modelList[0].listThumbnails.length; i++ ) {
    networkimages.add(new 
        NetworkImage(modelList[0].listThumbnails[i]));
}

new ImageCarousel(
    <ImageProvider>[
        new NetworkImage(CommonMethods.image_url + modelList[0].listThumbnails[0]),
        new NetworkImage(CommonMethods.image_url + modelList[0].listThumbnails[1],),
    ],
    interval: new Duration(seconds: 5),
    showCloseButtonOnZoom: true,
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass the `networkImages` List to the `ImageCarousel`. Something like this:

```
List<ImageProvider> networkimages = <ImageProvider>[];

for(int i=0 ; i< modelList[0].listThumbnails.length; i++ ) {
    networkimages.add(new 
        NetworkImage(modelList[0].listThumbnails[i]));
}

new ImageCarousel(
    networkimages,
    interval: new Duration(seconds: 5),
    showCloseButtonOnZoom: true,
),
```

Comment: I added the full example. You need to define networkimages as an `ImageProvider` and then add all `NetworkImages` to it.

Comment: Thanks @Bostrot, actually I was missing to add "CommonMethods.image_url" in the list.